# Assembly becoming 32bit specific when built in release rather than debug in VS2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, 32bit-64bit

I am having a strange issue when building assembly's for one of my modules.

I was getting errors when running on 64bit which I traced back to being related to the assembly being 32bit specific. Our modules are(or should) all be built to be bit agnostic.

Running CorFlags.exe on the assembly showed the following.

---

Version   : v2.0.50727

CLR Header: 2.5

PE        : PE32

CorFlags  : 11

ILONLY    : 1

32BIT     : 1 <-- Note the 32bit flag set to one!

Signed    : 1

---

However I then went back to rebuild the module and just so happened to build in debug mode. (Note: this is the simplified version of the story missing out the hours of solution testing, googling and a fight with a dragon :D)

This time when I checked CorFlags.exe it gave the following:

---

Version   : v2.0.50727

CLR Header: 2.5

PE        : PE32

CorFlags  : 9

ILONLY    : 1

32BIT     : 0

Signed    : 1

---

So now I am confused, having torn apart the visual studio build configs and found them to be exactly the same (i.e. all set to "Any CPU") I am now at a loss as to how to fix this.

What would cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build + Configuration Manager, select Release in the upper left combo.  Close.  Now use Project + Properties, Build tab and verify Platform Target.

Comment: Yeah I found the option it was located in 

>>Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile options.

>>Target CPU = AnyCPU

cheers tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's causing this behavior but here is a possible workaround:

Have you tried running CorFlags with /32BIT- flag to clear the 32BIT flag from the assembly? If it work you can add a postbuild step to cleat that flag.

Comment: Although this would probably fix the problem at a high level, I am sure that there must be a root cause of the problem and I would really like to discover what it is before the system is deployed. Thanks for your suggestion though :)